# How to Include LaTeX inline in Confluence Document

Tags: latex, confluence

I have seen [some documentation](https://bolosoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/196684/LaTeX+Math) here on how to include LaTeX in Confluence, but looking at the docs linked I am not clear on what I should expect to work out of the box and what needs a plugin from the Atlassian marketplace.

For example, I'd like to include the symbol sigma (Σ) in a confluence document. Looking at the link I'd expect `{\Sigma}` to create the Greek capital letter Sigma but it gives me a "Wiki Markup" entry rather than inline LaTeX. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like your link is to the documentation of a plugin by Bolo Software. I would guess that any LaTeX support will need to come through a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. That link appears broken. Do you recommend any particular ways to include LaTeX?

Comment: [MathJax](https://bitbucket.org/keysight/keysight-plugins-for-atlassian-products/wiki/Confluence%20Plugins/MathJax%20Plugin), while not directly LaTeX, uses LaTeX format and produces some pretty nice outputs. Plus it's free/open-source :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type the left opening brace (`{`) in the editor, an auto-complete suggestion list should appear. If you type `latex`, you should see the options available to you. Alternatively, you can click the add button in the top right of the editor ribbon, and select the LaTeX macro you want; inline, block, reference, etc.

That should open an editor window where you would type `\Sigma` or whatever body you want the macro to have.

If you type `{\Sigma}`, Confluence looks for a macro called `\Sigma`, fails to find one, so it defaults to Wiki Markup.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use an Addon on Atlassian marketplece. It will help you edit math equation on a confluence page.
It supports multi-input UI of selectable formula and LaTeX code input.
Using multi-input UI and live preview & Edit, any user who is not familiar with LaTeX syntax can edit math equation.
Please check details in the marketplace.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1224024
The AddOn supports Inlin and Block modes.

Answer (score -2):

For Confluence Cloud there is a marketplace plugin that can be embedded into the editor under `/math` shortcut. The plugin can be used by LaTeX powerusers (no mouse input, all the `\int_0^\infty` works as expected). On the other hand, it's easy to use for non-latex-capable people thanks to the virtual math keyboard that offers quick access to math symbols.

Equations are rendered as inline, encoded SVG. This way formulas load ultra-fast and scale properly.

The plugin is free to use for small Atlassian Cloud instances.

[Easy Math Equations for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1228577/easy-math-equations-for-confluence?)

(**Disclaimer** – This comment is about my Confluence plugin I wrote this summer)